# How does Chrome implement text scaling on android?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I created an HTML file and opened that on android Google Chrome but when I increased text scaling from Settings > Accessibility, some of the elements' font size became larger but the other ones didn't (Every inline-block element and some others remained at initial size).
I did the same on desktop Chrome from Settings > Appearance > Font size but every font size became larger.
Then I added the following code to my file to see what is going on and noticed Chrome on android doesn't increase root font size for text scaling but desktop Chrome does.

```
const rootEle = document.querySelector(":root");
const bodyEle = document.querySelector("body");
bodyEle.insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend",
  `root font size: ${window.getComputedStyle(rootEle).fontSize}`
);
```

Now I want to know how android Chrome implements text scaling to avoid this inconsistency in font sizes.
I have to mention that I haven't used any fixed units like `px` for font size and I tried this also on an HTML file without any styling with very simple HTML elements and the result was the same.